# Setting/clearing/enabling breakpoints in C code in Xcode 14 causes "Program ended with exit code: 1"

Tags: xcode, lldb

I'm trying to debug some older C code in my Xcode project. I've tried this on both my 2013 Intel MacPro and a 2022 MacBook Air M1, both running Xcode 14.2, with the same results.

Any time I set or clear a breakpoint, or try to enable one that is temporarily disabled, I get:

```
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

This would normally mean an untrapped error in the code, but this is code that works fine otherwise, and happens anywhere in the code at any time, click to make a breakpoint and it dies. Google and SO have a very few threads on this error, but nothing related to breakpoints.

In the following image, I am trying to debug why the output is printing zeros instead of the expected values. As there are many print statements that run before this, I inserted a break and disabled it. When the program gets to this point and is waiting for input, I click the breakpoint to enable it, and blam. The same occurs at any point in the code.

[image]

Comment: In order to set a breakpoint or re-enable it while the process is running, lldb needs to send a SIGSTOP to the process.  That can interrupt some system calls like read, etc - causing them to exit with an EINTR.  It's not uncommon for programs to forget to check that error.  I wouldn't be surprised if there's a read loop in you code somewhere that's mistaking the EINTR for a broken read and exiting with `return 1`.

Comment: Ah ha. Ok, that is unexpected but explains the situation in this case as the SIGSTOP would mostly likely be happening in a scanf, which I assume is causing the problem.

Comment: If you figure out that that is actually the cause, please transcribe that as an answer so others can find it.